# Build an arraylist of specific object looping recursive function on json object

Tags: android, json, function, recursion, kotlin

I am trying to get an array of custom object :

I have a json object which contains a list of question. Questions may have sub questions, and sub questions may have others sub questions. My json is like this:[image: Json array]

- The group contain the label question
- The conditions contain the responses
- Children contains others group/conditions/children

I need to loop on each member and create an arraylist of GroupConditions object to have the possibility to ask all question in the good order like this :

[image]

I'm blocked, can you help me. Sorry for my English. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're gonna have to use JSONElements and walk each one if it has children. Then determine what to do with the child based on the key. It will be tedious, but you can do it recursively at least. Not sure what the issue is that you are having, unless you are trying to grab all the json and put in an object, that won't work. You need to walk the tree and grab the elements as you find them and determine what object you are building at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be something like this:

```
class Question {
    val questions = listOf<Question>()
}

fun extractQuestions(questionList: List<Question>): List<Question> =
    questionList.flatMap { listOf(it) + extractQuestions(it.questions) }
```

Comment: There is `open: Boolean` property in object, that I think should be used.

Comment: Thank you Andrey, i ve just little bit adapted my code using the flatmap recursive method and it works !